# Is there a quick way to replace backwards after long sequence of ReplaceAll?

Tags: replacement, coding-style

I have done a lot of variable replacements in order to simplify equation so that it can be solved by mathematica command.  After getting the solution I have to go backwards in Replace All.  Is there a short cut for this?  For example,

```
r1=ReplaceAll[expr,a->b];
r2=ReplaceAll[r1,c->d];
r3=ReplaceAll[r2,e->f];
r4=ReplaceAll[r3,g->h];
Solution=Solve[r4];
r5=ReplaceAll[Solution,h->g];
r6=ReplaceAll[r5,f->e];
r7=ReplaceAll[r6,d->c];
answer=ReplaceAll[r7,b->a];
```

Is there a quick way to go backward in ReplaceAll, something like Evaluate (it does not work)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the definition of `expr`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the replacement like `g->h` followed by `h->g` can't be reversed in general because it results in loss of information if the original expression contains both `g` and `h`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could accomplish your replacements by first making a list of replacement rules

```
rules = {a -> b, c -> d, e -> f, g -> h}
```

Then you can apply them all in sequence using `Fold`

```
replaced = Fold[ ReplaceAll, expr, rules ]
```

If you need the results of each replacement in turn, you can use `FoldList` instead

```
{r1,r2,r3,r4} = FoldList[ ReplaceAll, expr, rules ]
```

Then you can apply the rules in reverse:

```
final = Fold[ ReplaceAll, Solve@replaced, Reverse/@rules ]
```

---

Note that, depending upon your needs, it *may* work to simply apply all the rules in one call to `ReplaceAll` :

```
replaced2 = expr /. rules
final2 = Solve@replaced2 /. Reverse/@rules
```

Comment: i think you do not need to use a `Fold`, `FoldList`  or any iteration construct.`ReplaceAll` will apply all the transformation rules on the expression in a single go. Therefore, in my answer i have avoided using an iteration construct

Comment: @AliHashmi Yes, that's exactly what I mentioned in the last few lines of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
rules = {a->b, c->d, e->f, g->h};
Solve[expr /. rules] /. (Map[Reverse]@rules)
```